# Corner ribbon text not centered properly (pure CSS, no images)

Tags: css

I have created a ribbon using pure CSS (no images), but the text in it is not centered. The text: NEW is now only partly visible. You can only read: NE

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/8kv6v/

How to fix this so the text NEW is centered in the ribbon?

Kind regards,
Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to this, is that the `div.ribbon-green` is very wide, and is positioned so that its center is at the right side. The E in NEW is the very center of the `div.ribbon-green`. So to get NEW centered in the part of the wrapper which is shown, we have to move the position of `div.ribbon-green`. I tried to move around a bit, and found that the following position works:

```
.ribbon-green {
  left: -10px;
  top: 5px;
}
```